# How to connect frontend and backend correctly?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, spring, angular, jsp

I'm new in the web programming. So, i have some trouble with understanding how to connect front and back ends. I'm writing on java. So, I have spring mvc and jsp(or another template engine like Apache FreeMarker etc.) as view layer. How to integrate there reactjs or angular2+ fron-tend frameworks? And should I do that stuff?
Is it actual to use java code in html (jsp) or ruby code in html (erb)? If it is actually, how to use front-end frameworks in this case?(Or it shouldn't be used?)
May be I must create something like RESTful back-end and integrate it with angular 2(as an example)? 
May be there is other way to integrate them? Could You explain me how should i create my web app? Or share with me some links by this topic? 
If there are several way to do what i ask, could you, also,  explain me advantages and disadvantages of each approach? And sorry for my English. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just google it, so may resources are already available for integrating these technologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frontend: things that run in the browser, that's based on HTML/CSS/JS

Backend: things that run on the server, Ruby, PHP, Python, Java, JavaScript/Node, bash scripts, DBMS

Front-end and back-end interact in two ways:

1- A simple blog case: When you type the URL of a specific post, your browser is making a HTTP request to the back-end. The back-end returns a HTTP response containing the HTML code interpreted by the browser. The only interaction between the two edges is indeed the HTTP flow.

2- A single-page, AJAX-powered application: It’s even more clear here that the only interaction is HTTP. The Javascript-powered front-end UI (or it could be any web, mobile or desktop application actually) sends HTTP requests to the back-end in order to read, create, update or delete data. The back-end returns HTTP responses containing the necessary information for the UI/webapp to change its state, display data to the user, etc...

Comment: I think in the advantage of the second case is that the logic is abstracted from the presentation, therefore you can use it with anything as fronted may it be a mobile app or web app you have written or even both. I think that is an API.